How to create two different global temp table parallely using two different task in an SSIS package that is using same oleDb connection
I have been trying to create two different task that are supposed to create two different global tables (need parallel creation of two global temp table) on the same DB server using same OLE DB connection. But i can find only one of the table is getting created.
It works if i create  two different OLE DB connection with the same DB credential and use it in each task. it is letting me create two global temp table on the same DB server parallely.
What am i missing here? How to create global temp tables parallely using an ssis on the same DB server?

Usually same connection can't run multiple statements at the same time. Why do you need this parallell stuff?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It's hard to say with just the information given.  But maybe you don't want a temp table at all?  Why not use a permanent table.  And you can name the permanent table "Staging_"  or "Staging." or something like that.  You can truncate the table at the beginning of your process.
